# How to sum up certain rows with Pandas and add the result to a defaultdict (large dataset)

Tags: python, pandas, defaultdict

I have a dataframe which consists out of 5 million name entries. The structure is as follows:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce4eI.png)

What one can read from this dataframe is that for instance the name *Mary* was given to 14 babys in the state Alaska (AK) in the year 1910. But the name *Mary* were also given to newborns in the other states and the following years as well.

What I would like to identify is: What is the most given name in that particular dataset overall and how often was that name assigned?

I have tried this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")

mask = df[["Name", "Count"]]

counter = 0
dd = defaultdict(int)

for pos, data in mask.iterrows():
    name = data["Name"]
    dd[name] = dd[name] + data["Count"]
    counter += 1

    if counter == 100000:
      break
print ("Done!")

freq_name = 0
name = ""

for key, value in dd.items():
    if freq_name < value:
        freq_name = value
        name = key

print(name)
```

This code works pretty well but only for up to 100.000 rows. However, when I use the presented code with the full dataset it takes ages.

Any idea or hint what I could improve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby('Name').Count.sum()` ?

Comment: instead of an image with the dataframe you should provide the code to generate the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can use something like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")
name, total_count = max(df.groupby('Name').Count.sum().items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```